# Proof that number is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can see clearly why $p$ in an even number implies that $p^2$ is even. 
But I don't understand completely why the opposite statement is also true, can someone show me why?
I can start with $$p^2 = 2a$$ but if I'll take the square root of both sides it'll lead to nothing.

Comment: Hint:  $(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1$

Comment: @lulu  it says that a square of an odd number is also odd, I've used it to prove the same statement about an even number, but I can't really tell how can it help me to prove the reversed statement

Comment: @Ozk I think the problem is asking you to use contraposition, using lulu's comment. See my answer.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  If you know that $(2n+1)^2$ is always odd, then clearly the square root of an even number can not be odd.

Answer (score 1):

Update: You want to prove:

$$\text{$p^2$ even} \implies \text{$p$ even}$$

which is equivalent by contraposition to:

$$\lnot (\text{$p$ even}) \implies \lnot(\text{$p^2$ even})$$

ie.

$$\text{$p$ odd} \implies \text{$p^2$ odd}$$

This can be proved using the definition by writing $p=2k+1$ and computing $p^2$.

---

If you don't want to prove it manually, it can be seen also as a direct consequence of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma), namely:

> If $q$ divides $ab$, where $q$ is prime and $a,b$ are integers, then $q$ divides $a$ or $q$ divides $b$.

Take $q=2$, $a=b=p$.

Comment: But I want to prove it manually

Comment: @Ozk: I updated my answer. I think there was previously an answer explaining this, I don't know why it was deleted.

Comment: What's the meaning of "ie." ?

Comment: The manual proof is only exist in an indirect way?

Comment: @Ozk: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-e

Comment: @Ozk: If you want to prove it without using contraposition, you'll need some "structural result" about prime numbers, such as Euclid's lemma (or more advanced result e.g. prime factorization)

Comment: An abbreviation for id est, a Latin phrase meaning “that is.” It indicates that an explanation or paraphrase is about to follow: “Many workers expect to put in a forty-hour week — i.e., to work eight hours a day.” (Compare e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at integers mod 2, then we have $\{0,1\}$ and $0^2  =0$ and $1^2 = 1$. $0$ corresponds to the even numbers, $1$ to the odd ones.